# Concatenating matching column values between 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

df1 has 5 columns and 3 rows. Column 'B' has same value for row1 and 2.

```
      A    B    C    D     E

      a    b    c    d     data1
      o    b    g    h     data2
      i    j    k    l     data3
```

df2 has 4 columns and 2 rows

```
       A     B    C   D

       x     b    z   o
       y     f    w   p
```

I want to update df2 by comparing the matching rows between df1 and df2 on column 'B' (the value is lower case 'b') and add a new column in df2 ('NewColumn') with data being concatenated from df1 on column 'B' ('data1:data2' )

updated df2

```
       A     B    C   D     NewColumn

       x     b    z   o     data1:data2
```

This need to be done for all matching rows between these 2 dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. `merge` the required columns of the other dataframein
2. `groupby` the columns and join the strings together as desired

---

```
(df2.merge(df1[['B','E']])
    .groupby([*df1.columns[:-1]])['E']
    .agg(':'.join).reset_index())

    A   B   C   D   E
0   x   b   z   o   data1:data2
```

Comment: Thank you much David !! One more question if I like to put a condition which says if column ‘D’ of df1 has value ‘h’ which means only ‘data2’ to be written in NewColumn of df2. Can you pls help ?

Comment: @RishimMittal I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @RishimMittal switch `df1[['B','E']]` to `df1.loc[df1['D'] == 'h', ['B','E']]` However, if there is only one row, then you cannot group and you will get an error, but if there are multiple `h` values, then you will be fine.